# How do I throttle onDragOver using the Drag and Drop API?

Tags: reactjs, webapi

I'm trying to implement the ability to re-order elements inside a list. On first sight, it looks trivial just use `onDragStart` for the item that I want to replace with `onDragOver` but the `onDragOver` fires too frequently and the elements get constantly replaced. Any ideas how to fix [this](https://usz2o0.csb.app/)?

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [names, setNames] = useState([
    "Obama",
    "Joe",
    "Donald",
    "George", 
    "Richard"
  ]);
  const [itemDragged, setItemDragged] = useState()
  const [itemDraggedOver, setItemDraggedOver] = useState()
  const handleDragStart = index => {
    console.log(index, ' was dragged')
    setItemDragged(index);
  }
  const handleDraggedOver = index => {
    console.log(itemDragged, ' was dragged over', index)

    const _names = [...names]
    let temp = _names[itemDragged]
    _names[itemDragged] = _names[index]
    _names[index] = temp
    console.log(_names)
    setNames(_names)
    setItemDraggedOver(index);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {
          names.map((name,idx) => {
            return (<li 
              draggable
              onDragStart={() => handleDragStart(idx)}
              key={idx}
              onDragOver={() => {
                handleDraggedOver(idx);
              }}
              >
                {name}
              </li>)
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```